# A few question about my function graph

Tags: calculus, limits

https://pasteboard.co/HPqwOcE.jpg

[image]

1-) Can I draw a function like that?

2-) If I draw, can I find it's equation?

3-) Is there a limit, as $x$ approaches to $2$ ?

I am trying to understand the limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *draw* a function like that, alright. To find the equation, notice that the function is really two straight lines joined end to end. Uptil $x=2$, the line is $y=3x$, and beyond $x=2$, the straight line is $y=\frac{1}{4}(x+22)$. So your function is:

$f(x)=\begin{cases}3x,& x\leq2\\\frac{1}{4}(x+22),& x>2\end{cases}$

As for the limit, you will have to evaluate the right and left hand limits separately because the function definition changes across $x=2$. What is $\lim_{x\to2^+} f(x), \lim_{x\to2^-} f(x)$?

[image: Question Graph]

Comment: Thank you, It is perfect.